# Closed subset of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

A disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a manifold with boundary of dimension $2$ sitting in $\mathbb{R}^2$. More generally, is it true that a closed subset of a smooth manifold always a manifold with boundary?

Comment: The question was deliberately left imprecise. If one knew exactly what one was asking all the time, you wouldn't learn as much. That said, the accepted answer below is the type of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the coordinate cross in $\mathbb{R}^2$: $X=\{(x,y) \mid x = 0 \text{ or } y = 0\}$. This set is closed, but it is not a submanifold because of the $0$ point.